# Redirect target URL misses slash after domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect all traffic to HTTPS and WWW.

Using this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But going to my domain `example.com/blog` redirects to `https://www.example.comblog`. This does not have a slash after the domain before the subdirectory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Required changing (adding a slash)
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
to
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]